# How-To get details of 401 Unauthorized from ASP.NET Core 2.1 API

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.NET API (built in Core 2.1) and when trying to call it from a test application, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized.  However, near as I can tell, the Access Token is fine.  Is there a way to get more details about what is invalid from the Authentication handler in ASP.NET Core 2.1?  If I can get some idea of what is wrong with the token, I should be able to find a solution to correct it, but right now I am stumbling around in the dark and just trying various things (most likely, I am just making it worse).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check logs or the events viewer of your server.

For your error, check if you're calling `app.UseAuthentication()` as the first method in `Configure()`, even before `UseMVC()`.

It will helps if you've mentioned subcode of the error :

```
401.1: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
401.2: Access is denied due to server configuration favoring an alternate authentication method.
401.3: Access is denied due to an ACL set on the requested resource.
401.4: Authorization failed by a filter installed on the Web server.
401.5: Authorization failed by an ISAPI/CGI application.
401.7: Access denied by URL authorization policy on the Web server.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what my problem was.

Comment: +1 This works for me after I moved the  `app.UseAuthentication()` above all the methods in `Configure()`

Comment: Moving UseAuthentication above UseMvc did it for me.

Comment: @FrqSalah hey, could you please link to where you got info for those codes? Thanks!

Comment: @andre_ss6 you can find everything here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525983(v%3Dvs.90)

Answer (score 2):

You should look in the server logs. It could be the way you're passing the token in your request. Example what it could be :

> I was doing:

```
GET https://localhost:44357/api/test 
Headers:   
    Bearer: {ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE}   
    Content-Type: application/json
```

> when I should have been doing:

```
GET https://localhost:44357/api/test 
Headers:   
    Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE}
    Content-Type: application/json
```

> https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/577